# How to prevent Firefox to moves automatically from one workspace to active workspace when hit an URL on that active workspace

Tags: firefox

on my Xubuntu 20.04 I have ten workspaces.

I start Firefox on the first workspace. When I click in fifth workspace on an URL which is in another application, that URL opened in Firefox but in the same time Firefox jump from first workspace to that active workspace. In other words, the Firefox instance on WS1 entirely moves to mine active (5th) workspace with all of the previously opened tabs, and a new tab with that URL.

How can I achieve that that when I hit an URL in application in another workspace, Firefox stay in the first workspace with a new tab in which is the just opened URL?

Comment: So you mean that the instance on WS1 entirely moves to your active (5th) workspace with all of the previously opened tabs, and a new tab? Or do you see a new Firefox window opening on the 5th workspace?

Comment: In Gnome Shell, a new tab would open in the open instance of Firefox, which remains on the current workspace.

Comment: @vanadium "So you mean that the instance on WS1 entirely moves to your active (5th) workspace with all of the previously opened tabs, and a new tab?"  Yes, I mean exactly that.

Comment: OK, indicate that clearly in your question (use "edit"). It is important that you very specifically explain the situation. As I said, it does not happen in Gnome Shell, and I am actually surprised it does happen in xfce. You will need to await people having xfce installed, though. I don't for the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution.
In XFCE4 Desktop environment one must set the following for this:
in Applications menu:
Settings > Window Manager Tweaks > Focus >
When a window raises itself: Switch to windows workspace

This way the window stay in it's workspace when raises itself.